# Login without all credentials passport

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, backend, passport-local

The problem is that in my User Schema I defined 3 inputs: name, surname and email. What if i want passport to make the user logged in only by email and password without writing name and surname?

Comment: U didn't mention that your userschema includes a password

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a defined way to do sign in
And for your question no sign in is done by inputting everything found in userschema its normally email/username and password
As long as the inputs (email/username) are unique your good to go
To do that
Just search for the row where email:req.body.email
And then once you have this row compare do
If(row.password.equals(req.body.password)
If true do your cookie or whatever your gonna do